# Assign values from a dictionary to a new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This my data frame

| City | sales |
| --- | --- |
| San Diego | 500 |
| Texas | 400 |
| Nebraska | 300 |
| Macau | 200 |
| Rome | 100 |
| London | 50 |
| Manchester | 70 |

I want to add the country at the end which will look like this

| City | sales | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| San Diego | 500 | US |
| Texas | 400 | US |
| Nebraska | 300 | US |
| Macau | 200 | Hong Kong |
| Rome | 100 | Italy |
| London | 50 | England |
| Manchester | 200 | England |

The countries are stored in below dictionary

```
country={'US':['San Diego','Texas','Nebraska'], 'Hong Kong':'Macau', 'England':['London','Manchester'],'Italy':'Rome'}
```

Comment: You can unwrangle it to a list and then set it via df["Country"] = list

Comment: The country dict isn't useful for looking up country code given a city. You should build a dict with key value pairs such as: {'San Diego':'US', 'Rome':'Italy', 'Texas': 'US'}. Then you should be able to populate the final column fairly easily

Comment: I thought of doing it just because there will be too much repetition in my data as I have close to 50 key values, wanted to find a way to reduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little complicated because you have lists and strings as the values and strings are technically iterable, so distinguishing is more annoying. But here's a function that can flatten your dict:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    nd = {}
    for k,v in d.items():
        # Check if it's a list, if so then iterate through
        if ((hasattr(v, '__iter__') and not isinstance(v, str))):
            for item in v:
                nd[item] = k
        else:
            nd[v] = k
    return nd

d = flatten_dict(country)
#{'San Diego': 'US',
# 'Texas': 'US',
# 'Nebraska': 'US',
# 'Macau': 'Hong Kong',
# 'London': 'England',
# 'Manchester': 'England',
# 'Rome': 'Italy'}

df['Country'] = df['City'].map(d)
```

Comment: it says country not defined

Comment: Is that the variable you store your dict in? That's what it is in your post.

Comment: Oh, I got you know and it worked as well. the code is bit complex for me to understand but it worked

Comment: @SteveKundukulangara basically it reverses the keys and values to create a new dict. But there's a complication because if the value of your original dict is a list you then need to iterate through that. So that `if ...` basically asks (is it a list)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using `geopy`
You can install geopy by `pip install geopy`
Here is the documentation : https://pypi.org/project/geopy/

```
# import libraries
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

# you need to mention a name for the app
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="some_random_app_name")

# get country name
df['Country'] = df['City'].apply(lambda x : geolocator.geocode(x).address.split(', ')[-1])
print(df)
         City  sales         Country
0   San Diego    500   United States
1       Texas    400   United States
2    Nebraska    300   United States
3       Macau    200              中国
4        Rome    100          Italia
5      London     50  United Kingdom
6  Manchester     70  United Kingdom

# to get country name in english
df['Country'] = df['City'].apply(lambda x : geolocator.reverse(geolocator.geocode(x).point, language='en').address.split(', ')[-1])
print(df)
         City  sales         Country
0   San Diego    500   United States
1       Texas    400   United States
2    Nebraska    300   United States
3       Macau    200           China
4        Rome    100           Italy
5      London     50  United Kingdom
6  Manchester     70  United Kingdom
```